# Generic RGB LEDs with Asus AURA compatible motherboard

Tags: motherboard, compatibility, led

Will this LEDs stripes work with a Asus motherboard AURA

WS2812B 5050 RGB LED Strip 30/60/144 LEDs/M ws2812 IC Individual Addressable 5V [[link ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/322525222591?ul_noapp=true)]

My mobo: [ROG-STRIX-Z370](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z370-E-GAMING/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they would be compatible.

However you can have a maximum of only **60 LEDs** in the strip, and don't go over **3M** in length, as this will affect brightness.

Comment: Thank you! Look a lot of haters voting me down without commenting.